# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space,I am using tomcat on the Mac Os

Tags: java, macos, tomcat

I tried diffrent ways to solve it.

1.add a new file called `setenv.sh` in `$tomcat_install_address/bin`, the content is:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=356m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=356m"
```

it didn't work;

2.set the `JAVA_OPTS` in the `catalina.sh` or the `catalina.bat`, it also didn't work;

I will appreciate it if you send me the `catalina.sh` to solve the problem, I have already spent 3 hours in it.

I am sure the problem is not caused by the code, because the project is run successfully on the windows OS.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Set JAVA_OPTS in tomcat server.xml, uninstall service and reinstall it. Hope this should solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry,I can't understand it,could you please give me an example?

Comment: I find it useful to use run rather than debug,thanks.

Comment: Debug also you can do create debug.bat file in tomcat bin dir and put below lines and save it: set CATALINA_HOME="D:\Apache_64bit\apache-tomcat-7.0.26_64bit"
set JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
catalina.bat jpda start